# avconv for converting mkv to mp4

Tags: raspbian, ffmpeg

I would like to convert a video file from mkv to mp4.
Usually (Debian 9, main laptop), I do:

```
$ ffmpeg -i input.mkv -c:v libx264 output.mp4
```

On the other hand, on raspbian ffmpeg is replaced with avconv. My question is: is there an equivalent avconv command for doing exactly the same thing?

I am aware of possible other alternatives for reaching the same goal (mvk -> mp4), as for example listed on this website, but it is spontaneous for me to start with easier attempts.

Comment: May I ask why you would like to [convert from an open and free format to a patent-encumbered one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_video_container_formats#Information)?

Comment: If you want to build ffmpeg from source, you can do it on the RPi: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/RaspberryPi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Your Raspbian must be old

- Raspbian Jessie (backports), Raspbian Stretch, and newer use `ffmpeg` from FFmpeg.
- Anything older uses the dead [counterfeit "`ffmpeg`" from the Libav fork](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9477756/1109017), and/or `avconv` which is also from Libav.

If your Raspbian doesn't provide `ffmpeg`, or you don't want to use the old Libav stuff, you can simply [download a binary of `ffmpeg`](https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/) for armel, armhf, or arm64. Which one to use depends on your Pi version.

## MKV to MP4

If the video and audio formats in the MKV file are supported by MP4, such as H.264 video and AAC audio, then you can just re-mux:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -c copy output.mp4
```

Otherwise, re-encode by removing `-c copy`.